# Create(Int32) the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I am clicking the `Create` button on the following view:

```
@model IEnumerable<BasicApplication.Address>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Person client = ViewBag.client;
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Person</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person.first_name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.Raw(client.first_name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person.last_name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.Raw(client.last_name)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
```

I am getting the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Int32)' in 'BasicApplication.Controllers.AddressController'

My Controller:

```
public class AddressController : Controller
{
    ClientsDataContext cdc = new ClientsDataContext();


    // GET: Address/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int id) // person id
    {
        Person client = cdc.getPerson(id);
        ViewBag.client = client;
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Address/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            Address newAdress = new Address()
            {
                description = collection["description"],
                street_address = collection["street_address"],
                city = collection["city"],
                province = collection["province"],
                postal_code = collection["postal_code"],
                country = collection["country"],
                person_id = id,
            };

            cdc.Addresses.InsertOnSubmit(newAdress);
            cdc.SubmitChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = id });
        }
        catch
        {
            Person client = cdc.getPerson(id);
            ViewBag.client = client;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I am supplying an ID in create method, not sure why this is happening. I just started working with MVC couple days ago so I'm very new.

Comment: In which line the error message is showing?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Doesn't say, or at least i cant find it. I added the whole error

Comment: how do you invoke the `Create(int id, FormCollection collection)` method? the error message indicates the passed value for `id` is null, which is not acceptable.

Comment: @TanvirArjel how do we do this?

Comment: @kennyzx I have another controller with that exact method and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your `Create` Action Link missing the `id` parameter value.So your `Create` `ActionLink` should be as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new {id = client.person_id })
```